# Limit of the quotient of binomials

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am interested in the asymptotics of the following quotient:
$$\binom{n−m}{m}/\binom{n}{m}$$
for $2m<n$. If $m$ is a constant, this goes to one for $n\to\infty$. What happens, if $m$ depends on $n$? Intuitively, the same should hold even for $m^2=o(n)$. How can it be shown, that the limit is one if and only if $m^2=o(n)$?

Comment: With $m:=\frac{n}{2}-1$ follows $0$ for $n\to\infty$ . For this test the Stirling formula is helpful.

Comment: I think, the complete asymptotics should be $1$ for $m^2=o(n)$, in $(0,1)$ for $m^2=cn$ and $0$ for $m^2\gg n$.

Comment: Sorry, I thought only about $2m<n$ but you meant $m^2=cn$ . I think the Stirling formula is really the best to answer your question. Why you don't use it ?!

Comment: Using Stirling, you end up at evaluating $\frac{(n−m)^{2n−2m}}{n^n(n−2m)^{n−2m}}$. But also here, I do not see how you would get the condition $m^2=o(n)$.

Comment: $m^2=o(n)$ means $\frac{m}{\sqrt{n} }\to 0$ : $\displaystyle \frac{(n-m)^{2n-2m}}{n^n(n-2m)^{n-2m}}=\frac{(\sqrt{n}-\frac{m}{\sqrt{n}})^{2n-2m}}{(\sqrt{n} -\frac{2m}{\sqrt{n}})^{n-2m}\sqrt{n}^n}\to\frac{\sqrt{n} ^{2n-2m}}{\sqrt{n} ^{n-2m}\sqrt{n} ^n}=1$